# How to lock a table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to lock a table in SQL Server ? I found running queries with lock and also read transactions but 
confused how to use these.

I have two processes which are reading a table first then updating data in it . I want only one to update and other get this update in its read . working of my processes is as follows:-

- Lock table
- read data
- update data if it is not updated by other process.
- release Lock.

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TABLOCKX` hint to lock entire table, but locking entire table is usually a bad idea, you might want to reconsider if you really need it.

If you want to ensure you're updating latest data, you can use `rowversion` column, and double check before update instead of locking entire table for reading.

Answer (score 1):

In your select statement you can provide a "select for update" [table hint](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187373.aspx): `with (updlock)`. Depending on what percentage of records you are updating and their physical distribution this might perform better than a table lock.

But as Fedor Hajdu pointed out, what you probably want is an optimistic locking scheme. Check out the documentation for the [READ COMMITTED SNAPSHOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175095%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) isolation level. You might also find this [article](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/01/implementing-snapshot-or-read-committed-snapshot-isolation-in-sql-server-a-guide/) useful as an introduction.